# How to use `useCall()` polkadot react-hook? Type issue

Tags: polkadot-js, api

I'm trying to use useCall() to add to polkadot js ui.

[image].

I've added the type interface:

```
/** @name UserSupersig */
export interface UserSupersig extends Struct {
    readonly user_supersigs: Vec<SupersigIdInfo>;
}
```

```
Argument of type 'PromiseRpcResult<AugmentedRpc<(user_account: string | AccountId | Uint8Array) => Observable<UserSupersig>>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'false | TrackFn | null | undefined'.
  Type 'PromiseRpcResult<AugmentedRpc<(user_account: string | AccountId | Uint8Array) => Observable<UserSupersig>>>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseResult<AnyFunction>'.
    Types of parameters 'user_account' and 'args_0' are incompatible.
      Type '[...any[], (result: unknown) => void | Promise<void>]' is not assignable to type '[user_account: string | AccountId | Uint8Array]'.
        Target allows only 1 element(s) but source may have more
```

Just trying to make sense of this error and how to fix.

Comment: It looks like a type mismatch and that a different amount of parameters from what you are giving are expected. The reason might be `...any[]` ? You can also submit an issue in the corresponding repo https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps if you think you are making the correct use of the call but still getting an error.

Comment: thanks, i'm looking for some docs on useCall, but cant seem to find